# Nodejs - obfuscate entire project - gulp-javascript-obfuscator

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, obfuscation

I am new to Nodejs and I have a Nodejs project with around 80 JS files distributed in different sub-directories and some of the js files are reused in the project. I would like to obfuscate the code as this project is shipped and installed on client systems where I do not have control and anyone who has access to the client can see the code.
Currently I am using gulp node-module to build a tar file of my project artifact. I came across posts which talks about javascript obfuscation using node-modules: javascript-obfuscator and gulp-javascript-obfuscator. The examples I have seen is for a single file obfuscation but not for an entire nodejs project.

I see a snippet on javascript-obfuscator npm page about obfuscating entire directory:

`javascript-obfuscator ./dist --output ./dist/obfuscated [options]
// creates a folder structure with obfuscated files under ./dist/obfuscated path`

I would like to use the gulp-javascript-obfuscator node-module to obfuscate my entire project. It would be great if one of you can guide me or post a snippet of Gulp task which can do this.

On a different note: If one of my js file is importing another file with `require(mycode-api)` then after the obfuscation does this change to `require(mycode-api-obfuscated)`.
Ref: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-obfuscator
https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/gulp-javascript-obfuscator

Answer (score 0):

To obfuscate entire project, try this:

```
gulp.src(['src/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(javascriptObfuscator())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var pipelines = require('readable-stream').pipeline;
const javascriptObfuscator = require('gulp-javascript-obfuscator');

gulp.task('min-js', function () {
    return pipelines(
        gulp.src('js/*.js'),
        javascriptObfuscator(),
        gulp.dest('dist')
    );
});
```